# Passing a java object to the HTTP Connector

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I have a requirement to pass an object to an HTTP connector (Not sure if I can use any other connector). The next step is convert an object to a CXML and make an outbound end point call to another API, get the response and convert it another java object. I am very new to Mule and need some inputs on this. Any pointers would be very helpful.

Can someone give me some good points where we have good links for mule implementation examples (apart from Mule in Action)

EDIT: code from OP's comment below

```
<flow name="object_serialization.mflowFlow1" doc:name="object_serialization.mflowFlow1">
  <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
  <component class="SerializeObject" doc:name="Java"/>
  <serializable-to-byte-array-transformer doc:name="Serializable to Byte Array"/>
  <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: How do you plan to serialize the Java object you'll be passing to the inbound HTTP endpoint?

Comment: I am planning to write it to a file and pass the path. Is there any other way of efficiently doing it? Please advise.

Comment: Hi David, What are the connectors I can use for for this requirement. Can you help/

Comment: How will you write the Java object to the file? Pure Java serialization? And you will HTTP POST the file location or the content of the file to Mule?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of pure java serialization. Can I use Mule for the who end to end implementation. I am very new to Mule but its very interesting and I would want to use this.

Comment: Java serialization is fragile, as you'll need to make sure you have binary compatible versions of the serialized classes on client and server side. In any case, you sure can use the HTTP connector to both POST requests (Mule as client) and receive them (Mule as server).

Comment: Can I use Mule for that? Can you tell me how to go about achieving this requirement in Mule?

Comment: I am actually interested in the Java object that you are willing to serialize... Can I have a look at the POJOs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your goal with Mule:

- On the client side:

  - Serialize the Java object with `serializable-to-byte-array-transformer`
  - HTTP POST it with an `http:outbound-endpoint`
- On the server side:

  - Receive the HTTP POST with an `http:inbound-endpoint`
  - Deserialize the Java object with `byte-array-to-serializable-transformer`

This assumes the Java object implements `java.io.Serializable`, which should be the case since you stated you want to use Java serialization. This also assumes that the necessary Java classes are available on the classpath of both client and server Mules.

Comment: Hi David, This is how my XML file looks. Can I not pass an object to the connector because it is going to called by another application and I am just hosting it this component.

Comment: <flow name="object_serialization.mflowFlow1" doc:name="object_serialization.mflowFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <component class="SerializeObject" doc:name="Java"/>
        <serializable-to-byte-array-transformer doc:name="Serializable to Byte Array"/>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    </flow>

Comment: Ugh XML in comments :( Do you know you can edit your question? What is the component for?

Comment: I have an application that will be talking to Ariba. Right now we are converting a java object to CXML and passing the stream to HTTP Connection. We would want to use Mule as the integration point.

Comment: So you're saying that the `SerializeObject` component does generate CXML from what is received over the `http:inbound-endpoint`?

Comment: yes that is right. The serialized object is converted into an input stream (CXML format) and pass over the http connector in plain java. What I am trying to simulate is the same thing in Mule

Comment: But this is in Mule, right? The flow runs in Mule, no?

Comment: Not yet. Thats is what I am trying to achieve. I am still in the learning phase. definitely need an expert help

Comment: Hi David.. Do you have more use case samples that would help me ?

Comment: Just a side question to this. How do I read the response from a google service with Mule outbound endpoint. I know that mule is an integration platform but sometimes we need to deal with the fact that the other person on the otherside is completely unknown.

Comment: @ArunGeorge The payload and inbound properties of the in-flight message will represent the response of the outbound HTTP interaction. This is completely independent of what/where is the remote service. What makes you think otherwise?